# Placing symbol in margin

Tags: symbols, margins, boxes

I am using

```
\def\margin_symbol{\rlap{\protect\makebox[-3cm]{X}}}
```

which I use in sections as `\section{\margin_symbol My Header}` to place an X 3cm to the left in the margin; however, my problem is that I'm both using it in sections and subsections and therefore the symbols are placed at different horizontally positions.

Can I somehow place the at an absolute position in the margin rather than 3cm to the left as it does now?

Comment: I think you're after `textpos` package, most likely?

Comment: As I understand, the problem arises in the table of contents, is that so? Unrelated, but avoid `\def\margin_symbol{...}` and use `\newcommand{\marginsymbol}{...}`, With the former you are defining the macro `\margin` with a nonempty parameter text.

Comment: Yes, the problem is primarily in the table of contents. I will use `\newcommand` instead of `\def`. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This implementation with the `tabto` package will work with certain limitations.  Primarily, when `\marginsymbol` appears in any sectioning macro argument, it must be the last item in the argument.  Second, if you are using a table of contents, or a chapter page-heading, you will need to use the optional argument of the sectioning macro to exclude the margin mark.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabto,lipsum}
\def\marginsymbol{\protect\marginsymbolhelper}
\def\marginsymbolhelper{\tabto*{-1cm}\makebox[0cm]{$\bullet$}\tabto*{\TabPrevPos}}
\begin{document}
\section[My Header]{My Header\marginsymbol}

\subsection{My subsection Header\marginsymbol}

this is an inline \marginsymbol test. \lipsum[1]

\subsection{My subsubsection Header\marginsymbol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

FOLLOW UP:

The OP asks if it can be done for the table of contents, as well.  Here is a way, but it does not address the issue of chapter-page headings that I cited above.  So, for the `article` class, where that is not a direct issue, I provide a revised version of `\marginsymbol[<length>]` with an optional length argument that is only applied in the toc as an added leftward offset, in order to handle the staggered entries of toc subcategories.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\newcommand\marginsymbol[1][0pt]{%
  \tabto*{0cm}\makebox[\dimexpr-1cm-#1\relax][r]{$\bullet$}\tabto*{\TabPrevPos}}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\bigskip
\renewcommand\marginsymbol[1][0pt]{%
  \tabto*{0cm}\makebox[-2cm][c]{$\bullet$}\tabto*{\TabPrevPos}}

\section{My Header\marginsymbol}

\subsection{My subsection Header\marginsymbol[23pt]}

\subsubsection{My subsubsection Header\marginsymbol[55pt]}

\section{My New Header\marginsymbol}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is it also possible to have the same behaviour in the table of contents? I think the symbols should be placed exactly at same horizontal position as they are at the sections

Comment: @Jamgreen Please see my FOLLOW UP for one possibility.

Comment: Why do the symbols have different sizes? Can't I find a package which gives me the possibility to write something like `\section{My header \symbol}` with `\newcommand{\symbol}{\horizontaltextposition{0cm}{symbol}}` where `0cm` refers to relative position from the left margin, having these symbols being placed every place where `\symbol` is used - both in toc and sections?

Comment: @Jamgreen The symbols have different sizes, because the sectioning fonts have different sizes.  I thought that was a plus, but I'll see if I can override that.

Comment: @Jamgreen  In the `\renewcommand` of `\marginsymbol`, just replace `{$\bullet$}` with `{\normalsize$\bullet$}` if you want bullets of consistent size.