# Symbol on a fixed horizontal position in the margin

Tags: positioning, margins

I'm constructing an exercise sheet and would like to mark the thougher exercises.

Based on [Placing symbol in margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250659/placing-symbol-in-margin) I'm placing an symbol in the left margin. It works pretty well, but when I enumerate in more levels the horizontal position of the image shifts.

Is there a way to fix the horizontal position at like 2 cm from the page bound?

#### MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabto} %%symbol in left margin
\usepackage{manfnt}
\def\warningsymbol{\protect\marginsymbolhelper}
\def\marginsymbolhelper{\tabto*{-2cm} {\dbend} \tabto*{\TabPrevPos}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item \warningsymbol Exercise 1
    \item Exercise 2
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \warningsymbol Subexercise 1
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't using `\marginpar` for anything else...  You can adjust the distance using `\marginparsep`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage{manfnt}
\reversemarginpar
\newcommand{\marginsymbol}{\marginpar{\hfill\dbend}}
\usepackage{showframe}% debugging tool

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Exercise 1 \marginsymbol
    \item Exercise 2
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Subexercise 1 \marginsymbol
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: I had to add `\leavevmode` in front of the `\marginpar`, but it works like a charm! Thanks!